# JavaScript function parseInt() doesn't parse numbers with leading 0 correctly

Tags: javascript, parseint

I have some zeros prior to a positive integer. I want to remove the zeros so only the positive integer remains. Like '001' will only be '1'. I thought the easiest way was to use parseInt('001'). But what I discovered is that it don't works for the number 8 and 9. Example parseInt('008') will result in '0' instead of '8'.

Here are the whole html code:

```
<html> <body>
<script>
var integer = parseInt('002');
document.write(integer);

</script>
</body> </html>
```

But can I somehow report this problem? Do anyone know an another easy workaround this problem?

Comment: also, stripping leading zeros by using `parseInt('008').toString()` is very clumsy, consider using `RegExp` instead

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is documented behavior: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp

Strings with a leading '0' are parsed as if they were octal.

Comment: MDN docs are generally of much higher quality than their w3schools counterparts.  [Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) the relevant MDN page.

Comment: [FireFox 21](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/21) has curiously decided to [remove this functionality](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=786135). Chrome has apparently been that way for a while: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542377

Answer (score 15):

You have to specify the base of the number (radix)

```
parseInt('01', 10);
```

Comment: Yep, and a JS code quality tool like JSLint (http://www.jslint.com/) can give you a heads up about it :)

Answer (score 3):

Number prefixed with zero is parsed as octal.

Comment: That's not the [whole story](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) -- it's browser and version dependent.

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually a bug. For legacy reasons strings starting with 0 are interpreted in octal, and in octal there is no digit 8. To work around this you should explicitly pass a radix (i.e. `parseInt("008", 10)`).