# How come parseInt("08") = 0, parseInt("07") = 7

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript function parseInt() doesn't parse numbers with leading 0 correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481524/javascript-function-parseint-doesnt-parse-numbers-with-leading-0-correctly)

Strange issues when parsing in JS occur.

```
parseInt("08")
//The result is: 0

parseInt("07")
//The result is: 7
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: I havn't got this issue!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because of the 0 prefix. It tells Javascript the number is Octal, in base-8. 8 isn't a legal octal digit.

Use `parseInt("8")` instead, or as @Gumbo so correctly pointed out - `parseInt("08", 10)`

Comment: … or `parseInt("08", 10)`.