# Why does parseInt return NAN for "08" string and return 7 for "07" string?

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a simple apps script as follows:

```
function testeBug() {
  Logger.log(parseInt("07"));
  Logger.log(parseInt("08"));
}
```

And here's the logger output:

[13-06-19 23:09:13:130 BRT] 7.0
[13-06-19 23:09:13:130 BRT] NaN

Why this is happening?
I'm using Google Apps Script

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come parseInt("08") = 0, parseInt("07") = 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652305/how-come-parseint08-0-parseint07-7) - octal in JavaScript - 8 is not valid octal digit.

Comment: I'm using GOOGLE APPS SCRIPT not Java Script

Comment: Altought the same solution worked for it.

Comment: Google seem to have slightly different view of "GOOGLE APPS SCRIPT not Java Script" :  "Google Apps Script **is a JavaScript** cloud scripting language that lets you extend Google Apps and build web applications" (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)

Comment: Alexei, thanks for your explanation. I didn't notice that. +1 in your comment.

Comment: Should be able to use new Number() in it's place

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to pass in the radix parameter to [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
parseInt("08", 10);
```

Failure to do so causes some browsers to treat strings with a leading zero as base-8, which is what you're seeing, since 07 in base-8 is 7, while 08 is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

07 is valid octal notation, 08 is not.