# parseInt() sometimes returning NaN

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to parse a DateItem response from a form so that it fits the form "M/D/YYYY" (ie 2014-08-05 would translate to 8/5/2014). Since the ItemResponse is of type String, I wrote the following to manipulate it:

```
s = s.replace(/(\d{0,4})\-(\d{0,2})\-(\d{0,4})/,'$2/$3/$1');

var arr = s.split('/');

return parseInt(arr[0]) + '/' + parseInt(arr[1]) + '/' + parseInt(arr[2]);
```

But `parseInt(arr[0])` just randomly started returning NaN a couple days ago. `arr[0]` is not null when it comes time to parse, and it's of type string. Only that value in the array has the problem. I parseInt to remove the preceding 0 on single digits. Any thoughts?

Comment: if you refer to the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), the radix is not really optional... but I know we are lazy sometimes ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Why does parseInt return NAN for "08" string and return 7 for "07" string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204249/why-does-parseint-return-nan-for-08-string-and-return-7-for-07-string?rq=1)

Basically, a leading 0 indicates that it is a number in octal.  8 is not a valid octal digit, hence NaN.  Use parseint(arr[0], 10) to specify the base.  You'll probably want to do the same for arr[1].

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)), this will return a formatted date string in a format of your choosing.

For your example:

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(formDataDateValue), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "M/d/yyyy");
```