# new Date() function creating invalid date for specific months (Sept, Oct only)

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working with date strings in Google App Script. I'm converting the strings to date objects, but having difficulty with specific dates.

The below code creates 4 dates for Aug, Sept, Oct, and Nov and converts them to dates using new Date().

```
function myFunction() {
  var date1 = "2016-07-18T13:44:00.000+0000";    
  var date2 = "2016-08-01T13:44:00.000+0000";      
  var date3 = "2016-09-01T13:44:00.000+0000";      
  var date4 = "2016-10-01T13:44:00.000+0000";

  var fizedDate1 = dateFix(date1);      
  var fizedDate2 = dateFix(date2);    
  var fizedDate3 = dateFix(date3);    
  var fizedDate4 = dateFix(date4);

  return 0;
}

function dateFix(date){
  var fixedDate = new Date(date.slice(0,4),parseInt(date.slice(5,7)),date.slice(8,10),parseInt(date.slice(11,13)),date.slice(14,16),date.slice(17,19));
  return fixedDate;
}
```

However, as my debugger below shows, the dates for Sept (08) and Oct (09) are invalid dates.

[image: Link to debugger showing invalid dates]

I've tried changing the numbers for all the other parameters of new Date(), but only the month and only for the inputs 08 and 09 create invalid dates.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: The parameter for the month is zero based.  In your log, the first fixed date states "Aug", and the month number is 07.  You must subtract 1 from all the month numbers.  That probably isn't the fix for the "invalid Date" however.  You should separate out the `date.slice(x,x)` parameters and log them with `Logger.log()` to see what is happening there.

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652305/how-come-parseint08-0-parseint07-7

Comment: You shouldn't need to use *parseInt* at all, just pass the string values. If [more than one argument is passed](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date), they are converted to number as if by `Number(value)`. In the case of the month, use `date.slice(5,7) - 1` since the month number must be decremented and the minus operator will coerce the string to number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script has a strange bug with parseInt("08") and parseInt("09"), you can fix it by specifying parseInt to work with decimals, for example parseInt("08",10):

```
function myFunction() {
  var date1 = "2016-07-18T13:44:00.000+0000";    
  var date2 = "2016-08-01T13:44:00.000+0000";      
  var date3 = "2016-09-01T13:44:00.000+0000";      
  var date4 = "2016-10-01T13:44:00.000+0000";

  var fizedDate1 = dateFix(date1);      
  var fizedDate2 = dateFix(date2);    
  var fizedDate3 = dateFix(date3);    
  var fizedDate4 = dateFix(date4);

  return 0;
}

function dateFix(date){
  var fixedDate = new Date(date.slice(0,4),parseInt(date.slice(5,7),10),date.slice(8,10),parseInt(date.slice(11,13),10),date.slice(14,16),date.slice(17,19));
  return fixedDate;
}
```

Comment: Not really a bug. In older implementations, *parseInt* treated numeric literals starting with `0` as octal where no radix was provided. The simple solution is don't use *parseInt*, just pass the strings and remember to subtract 1 from the month. :)