# Timestamp conversion difference between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, firefox, integer

I'm currently running into trouble when dealing with timestamps. I am debugging the following, exactly same code in Chrome 24.0.1312.56 m and Firefox 18.0.1 console:

```
new Date(parseInt('2012'), parseInt('09') - 1, parseInt('30')).getTime()/1000
```

When I execute it in **Chrome** I get:

```
1348956000
```

And when I execute it in **Firefox** I get:

```
1325199600
```

**Question**: What is the problem here?

Comment: You are asking for the time in milliseconds at different times, so it only makes sense that the timestamp should be different. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really. I am constructing the date and then I retrieve the milliseconds. I am not requesting the current time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `parseInt('09')`:

- Chrome 24 seems to return **9**
- FireFox 18 seems to treat the number as [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) therefore returns **0** (the 0 is parsed but 9 is not)

Quote from [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_Interpretations_with_No_Radix) documentation:

> Although discouraged by ECMAScript 3, many implementations interpret a
>   numeric string beginning with a leading 0 as octal.
>   [...]
>   The ECMAScript 5 specification of the function parseInt no longer
>   allows implementations to treat Strings beginning with a 0 character
>   as octal values.
>   [...]
>   Since many implementations have not adopted this behavior as of 2011,
>   and because older browsers must be supported, always specify a radix.

Solution: revise your code and explicitly specify the radix parameter:

```
new Date(parseInt('2012', 10), parseInt('09', 10) - 1, parseInt('30', 10)).getTime()/1000
// 1348945200
```

Comment: Mozilla are amending Firefox to follow Chrome now: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=786135

Comment: The fix for the issue @Robin is referring to has landed in Firefox 21. Starting in Firefox 21, `parseInt('09') === 9`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/21